# How to ignore broken resource to getting failed HTTP requests in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm having trouble with the option **Retrieve all embedded resource option** in **HTTP request Advance tab** as it retrieve all resources and if there is any resource broken  whole **Sampler** getting failed. Is there any method to avoide sample getting failed due to resource failures (Ex favi.ico).or is there any similar option as such in **Loadrunner** :  **List non critical resource errors as warnings**

Answer (score 4):

Failing of the parent HTTP Request sampler by the underlying embedded resource failure is controlled by `httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources` property.

If you want to permanently "tell" JMeter to ignore failures of the embedded resources - add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true
```

If you want the change to be ad-hoc - you can pass the property via `-J` command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jhttpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true -n -t test.jmx ...
```

References:

- [Miscellaneous configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you should be able to remove the unnecessary resource by using a GET method request with some setting like the HTTP Cookie Manager, HTTP Cache Manager and User Defined Variables.